# Cambiar carácter/letra en String de lugar a través de una consulta en DataTable (linq)

Tags: c#, linq

¡Hola!, verán, estoy intentado realizar una consulta con Linq desde un DataTable, este DataTable contiene montos con signos negativos a la izquierda (como naturalmente es), ejemplo:

-200

-250

Lo que busco es mediante la consulta convertir a lista dicha columna y posteriormente tratarla para pasar el signo negativo del lado izquierdo al lado derecho así

200-

250-

La query que he realizado para extraer la información del DataTable y pasarla a un String es la siguiente:

```
String.Join(Environment.NewLine, (From r In tablaMonto Select r.item(“Column1”)))
```

La idea es poder pasarla a .List().ForEach(xi => xi..) pero me arroja error de sintaxis o bien alguna otra manera de hacerlo en una sola consulta?

¡Saludos!

Comment: No se si entiendo mucho tu pregunta. Los datos en esa columna son de tipo string? lo que quieres es obtener una lista con todas esas cantidades con el signo menos cambiado de sitio? Las cantidades son todas negativas o tambien puede haber cantidades positivas sin signo?

Comment: @Pikoh también puede haber cantidades positivas, y si son de tipo string

Comment: Mira a ver si lo que pongo en mi respuesta es lo que buscas.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Como casi siempre, hay varias opciones para conseguir esto que pides.

Una opción es simplemente usar `Select`, comprobando si la columna contiene o no el carácter `-`, y en ese caso se hace un `Split` para quitarlo y agregarlo al final (podría también hacerse con `Substring`), y si la columna no contiene `-`, simplemente se retorna su valor.

En código:

```
var listaCantidades = tablaMonto.AsEnumerable().Select(x => x.Field<string>("Column1").Contains('-') ? 
                                                                            x.Field<string>("Column1").Split('-')[1] + "-" :
                                                                            x.Field<string>("Column1"));
```

---

Vb.net

```
String.Join(Environment.NewLine,tbImporteML.AsEnumerable()
           .Select(Function (x) If(x.item("Column1").ToString.Contains("-"), 
                          x.Item("Column1").ToString.Replace("-","") + "-",
                          x.Item("Column1").ToString)))
```

Comment: Listo!

`String.Join(Environment.NewLine,tbImporteML.AsEnumerable().Select(Function (x) If(x.item("Column1").ToString.Contains("-"),  x.Item("Column1").ToString.Replace("-","") + "-", x.Item("Column1").ToString)))` 

Para VB.Net, ¡mil gracias!